# GDBServer wont start on host machine

Tags: gdb, embedded-linux, remote-debugging

I migrated from my old Linux Mint to the new Ubuntu 18.04. and doing this I am trying a "newer" version of Eclipse. Therefore I installed Eclipse Photon and set up my remote application debugging like I did for Eclipse 3.8., using the Oselas Toolchain and a CortexA8.

The problem I am facing is, that the GDBServer on the host machine won't start automatically. After a successful connection I have to start it on my own:

[image]

Is there any new feature that exits the server immediately after starting?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit further? Like what do you type in manually that you want to have automated

Comment: @MauriceRandomNumber You can see the steps in the attached picture: the first row printed in black is what should work automatically: chmod the file and start the server. However, the server wont start, i have to do it on my own: manually typed in in green. That fixes the problem and the debugging starts at the main function. That is what happens automatically in my older Eclipse version.